# Layout id conflict in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Getting some object from the layout file (say, test.xml) requiring setting this layout in the activity. For example if the button has an id "@+id/btn" then I can't get it by findViewById(R.id.btn) because it throws NullPointerException, I have to set this layout as setContentLayout(test.xml) and only then get the button. The question is how can I get the object from layout file in a class which isn't an activity => I can't set layout there.

Comment: The question is why would you want to do that? Why finding a view in a context in which it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use an inflater:

take a look at the doc:

[inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

as class overview says

> This class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects

Answer (score 1):

Use inflater:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html